# Как менять цвет в столбце "Статус", в зависимости от значения?

Tags: php

Проблема такая: есть таблица заявок на починку разных видов быт-техники. Когда добавляю новую заявку, статус заявки должен быть первоначально "Новый-необработан"(красным цветом), в модальном окне обрабатываю эту новую запись там же выбираю специалиста и статус (статусы у меня 3 видов: "Обычный", "Срочный" и "Сверх-срочный") после обработки, в столбце "статус" должен закрашиваться цветами "желтый", "фиолетовый" и "зеленый" в зависимости от статуса, помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой.

вывожу данные в таблицу файл index.php

```
echo "<tr id='stTable5'>
        <td id='stTable0'>ID заявки</td>
        <td>Дата и время заявки</td>
        <td>Дилер</td>
        <td>Номер дилера</td>
        <td>Проблема</td>
        <td>Кол/во заявок</td>
        <td>Срочность</td>
        <td>Специалист</td>
        <td>Номер специалиста</td>
    </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo    '<tr>';
    echo    '<td id="stTable5">  <a href="post.php?post_id='.$row['id'].'" onclick="newMyWindow1(this.href); return false"?> '.$row['id'].' </a></td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['dealer'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['phone_dealer'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['problem'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['kol_zayavok'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['name_tekhnik'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['phone_tekhnik'].'</td>';
    echo    '</tr>'; 
};
    echo '</table>';
```

?>

а это обработчик. Модальное окно

```html
if(isset($_POST['save']))
   {
     $id            = $_POST['id'];
   $date          = $_POST['date'];
   $name_tekhnik  = $_POST['name_tekhnik'];
   $phone_tekhnik = $_POST['phone_tekhnik'];
      $dealer        = $_POST['dealer'];
      $kol_zayavok   = $_POST['kol_zayavok'];
      $problem       = $_POST['problem'];
      $status        = $_POST['status'];
      $phone_dealer  = $_POST['phone_dealer'];
            
     $result2 = mysql_query (" UPDATE zayavka SET name_tekhnik= '$name_tekhnik', phone_tekhnik = '$phone_tekhnik'        WHERE id = '$post_id' ");
   }
?>

<div id="payment-info">

<div class="content">

<form method="post" action="">
 <ul>
  <h2>Информация о заявке:</h2>
  <li><b>ID заявки:</b> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Дилер:</b> <?php echo $row['dealer']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Номер дилера:</b> <?php echo $row['phone_dealer']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Срочность:</b> <?php echo $row['status']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Время принятия заявки: </b> <?php echo $row['date']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Количество заявок:</b> <?php echo $row['kol_zayavok']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Специалист:</b> <?php echo $row['name_tekhnik']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Номер специалиста:</b> <?php echo $row['phone_tekhnik']; ?></li>
  <li><b>Проблема:</b> <?php echo $row['problem']; ?></li>
    <p>
        <b>Выберите специалиста:</b></p>
    <p> 
 <?php

   echo '<select name="name_tekhnik">';
   echo '<option selected value="">Выберите специалиста</option>';

         $result = mysql_query ("SELECT name_tekhnik FROM tekhnik ORDER BY name_tekhnik", $db);
         $myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
         do {
           printf ("<option id='nameTekhnik'>%s</option>", $myrow["name_tekhnik"],$myrow["name_tekhnik"]);
         }
         while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result));

   echo '</select>';
 ?>                                                      
    </p>

    <p>
        <b>Номер телефона специалиста:</b></p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="phone_tekhnik" class="inp" value=" " />
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="save" class="button" value="Отправить" />
    </p>

    <?php 
     if ($result2 == 'true') {
      echo "Данные успешно обновлены!<br>";
      } 
  ?>
</form>

</div>

</div>

<p class="text-center"><a href="" onclick="window.close();" title="Закрыть окно" id="close">Закрыть</a></p>
```

Comment: [if\elseif или switch](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php) - попробуйте

Comment: Nilsan, я новичок еще, не подскажите как прикурить к моему коду?(

Comment: У вас есть _echo    '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';_ вот её через if пускайте как вариант. типа _if ($row['status'] == 1) {echo '<td style="color:red;"';}_ подобным образом.

Comment: спасибо большое. помогло